# How do you fetch all rows data but only display only 10 rows in JDBC?

Tags: java, jdbc

I am writing a small program to interact with databae. And I want JDBC to get all the data but only display 10 rows. I know I need to add some conditions inside the while loop, but not sure how to do it.

```
 String queries [] = {query1,query2,query3};
      
      
      //loop for running every queries
      for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
          
          long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
          ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(queries[j]);
          ResultSetMetaData rsMetaData = rs.getMetaData();
          int count = rsMetaData.getColumnCount();

          
      //get column name
          for(int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
              System.out.print(rsMetaData.getColumnName(i) + ", ");
          }
              System.out.print("\n");
      
      //get rows
              
          while(rs.next()) {
              
              
              for(int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
                  
                  System.out.print(rs.getString(i) + ", ");
                }
            
              System.out.print("\n");
          }
        
          System.out.print("------------------------------------");
      
      long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
      System.out.println("\nThe query " + (j+1) + " took "+(endTime-startTime)+" milliseconds.\n");
      rs.close();
      }
```

Comment: Do you want 10 rows per query, or 10 rows in total?

Comment: 10 rows per query

Comment: *Why* do you want to get all the rows if you're only going to display 10 of them? This is a sheer waste of time and space, not to mention database server load. Use `LIMIT 10` in the query.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to limit outputting just 10 rows. Here are just 2 examples.

Using a counter:

```java
int rowCounter = 0;
while(rs.next()) {
    for(int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
        System.out.print(rs.getString(i) + ", ");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
    rowCounter++;              // after printing a row, increment counter
    if (rowCounter >= 10) {    // counted at least 10 rows
        break;                 // break out of the while-loop
    }
}
```

Using ResultSet.getRow():

```java
while(rs.next() && rs.getRow() <= 10) {  // ResultSet.getRow() returns the current row index
    for(int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
        System.out.print(rs.getString(i) + ", ");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```